# How to join 2 tables that has 2 where clauses

Tags: sql, join

I have a working code where the first query will select all the comments by a user and the other will select each topic of that comment and select only the topics the user comment on it but he is not the creatordon't. It is like a subscribed topic page. The problem is I can't make it in a single line query and I need it for pagination.

My original code is this:

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM tbl_comment WHERE user_id='$selected_user' GROUP BY topic_id";
    $res=mysql_query($qry);
        if(mysql_num_rows($res)==0)
            {
                echo "<tr><td colspan=2><br>No Topic(s) Subscribed.</td></tr>";
            }
        else
            {
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
                    {
                        $subcid = $row['topic_id'];
                        $qry2="SELECT * FROM tbl_topic WHERE topic_id='$subcid' AND user_id!='$selected_user'";
                        $res2=mysql_query($qry2);
                        while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($res2))
                            {
                                //echo output
                            }
                        }

                }
```

these are my two tables

```
tbl_topic
----------
topic_id
topic_title
user_id




tbl_comment
----------
comment_id
comment_message
user_id
topic_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in your question ... select only the topics the user don't comment on....

```
Select Tp.topic_Id , Tc.User_Id
From tbl_topic Tp
Inner Join tbl_comment Tc
   On  Tp.topic_Id = Tc.topic_Id
   And Tp.User_Id != Tc.User_Id
```

Comment: oops, my question is wrong, sorry, i mean select only the topics the user comment on but he is not the creator. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean subquery? Try this..

```
select * from tbl_comment where user_id in(
    select user_id from tbl_topic where topic_id='$subcid' and user_id!='$selected_user'
)
group by topic_id
```